# Split a string and add into `tuple`

Tags: python

I know of only two simple ways to split a string and add into `tuple`

```
import re

1. tuple(map(lambda i: i, re.findall('[\d]{2}', '012345'))) # ('01', '23', '45')

2. tuple(i for i in re.findall('[\d]{2}', '012345')) # ('01', '23', '45')
```

Is there other simple ways?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd go for

```
s = "012345"
[s[i:i + 2] for i in range(0, len(s), 2)]
```

or

```
tuple(s[i:i + 2] for i in range(0, len(s), 2))
```

if you really want a tuple.

Comment: +1.  I generally avoid regular expressions unless they're really needed, but in this case I would just do `tuple(re.findall('..', s))`.

Answer (score 2):

Usually one uses tuples when the dimensions/length is fixed (with possibly different types) and lists when there is an arbitrary number of values of the same type.

What is the reason to use a `tuple` instead of a `list` here?

Samples for tuples:

- coordinates in a fixed dimensional space (e.g. 2d: `(x, y)` )
- representation of `dict` key/value-pairs (e.g. `("John Smith", 38)`)
- things where the number of tuple components is known *before* evaluating the expression
- ...

Samples for lists:

- splitted string (`"foo|bar|buz"` splited on `|`s: `["foo", "bar", "buz"]`)
- command line arguments (`["-f", "/etc/fstab")`
- things where the number of list elements is (usually) not known before evaluating the expression
- ...

Comment: `Tuple` is necessary because the library that I use takes the one

Comment: ok, but then the library wants exactly a `n`-tuple I expect (where `n` is fixed). Say the library wants 3-tuples, then I'd go the explicit way: `call_library((arg1, arg2, arg3))`. Or when you're really sure about the length of a `list`: `call_library(tuple(my_3_element_list))`

Comment: ok, thanks, I see. Nevertheless I think my point is the way to go. That's not a tuple, it's a list!

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative:

```
s = '012345'
map(''.join, zip(*[iter(s)]*2))
```

Or if you need a tuple:

```
tuple(map(''.join, zip(*[iter(s)]*2)))
```

This method of grouping items into n-length groups comes straight from the documentation for [`zip()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#zip).

Comment: Hm.. +1, a very interesting solution!

Answer (score 0):

Python 3

Here I make the assumption that the OP defines "simpler" as not using regular expressions.

Given a strings in a list `["jim_bob", "slim_jim"]` that have some common pattern:

```
fileNameToTupleByUnderscore = lambda x: tuple(x.split('_'))
print(list(map(fileNameToTupleByUnderscore, ["jim_bob", "slim_jim"])))
```

Returns

```
[('jim', 'bob'), ('slim', 'jim')]
```

Note that you can add a `strip('_')` before the `split('_')` if you want to exclude trailing underscores.